# Trying to superimpose the pdf of the gamma distribution onto the histogram

Tags: r, statistics

I require some help to superimpose the gamma distribution onto the histogram

```
x <- c(200,79,102,60,120,81,34,21,127,98,60,34,50,38,101,31,58,50,52,85,69,47,88,85,120,40,70,80,75,91,14,50,20,45,51,63,65,49,85,20,56,45,54,50,48,104,69,87,76,63,84,60,21,30,28,14,58,200,69,75,28,83,102,104,98,40,56,74,45,40,57,105,75,16,243,63,30,45,70,31,30,107,50,30,75,63,124,69,73,26,131,65,80,26,30,40,165,10,90,46,21,23,80,31,90,120,60,43,145,30,40,18,150,30,45,127)
```

Assuming a gamma distribution for this data, I computed the maximum likelihood estimates of this data.

```
gamma.fit <- MASS::fitdistr(x,densfun="gamma")
> gamma.fit
      shape         rate    
  3.041098377   0.045302228 
 (0.379119742) (0.006138772)
```

Next, I tried to plot the pdf of this gamma distribution with the following estimates.

```
pdf1 <- function(x) dgamma(x,shape=3.041098377,rate=0.045302228)
```

However, when I tried to `plot(pdf1)` or `curve(pdf1)`, this error comes out:

```
Error in curve(pdf1) : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

I have tried `PDF1 <- Vectorize(pdf1)` and `curve(PDF1)` and the same error comes out.

I have no trouble plotting the histogram.
Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Try `plot(pdf1(x))` and `curve(pdf1(x))`.

Comment: hi Phil! plot(pdf1(x)) worked but I am getting the same error for curve(pdf1(x)) :(

Comment: I'm not getting an error with your code and `curve(pdf1(x))`. Is there something else you are doing?